# VUE - Call a function after v-for has done looping

Tags: vue.js, v-for

This is my approach of calling a method after v-for has done looping. It works perfectly fine but i still want to know if there's a better approach than this or if vue is offering something like v-for callback.
**Parent Component**

```
<template>
    <loader-component v-show="show_loader" />
    <list-component @onRendered="hideLoader"/>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    components: {
        loaderComponent,
        listComponent
    },
    data() {
        return {
            show_loader: true
        }
    }
    methods: {
        hideLoader() {
            this.show_loader = false;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

**List Component**

```
<template>
    <item-component v-for="(item, key) in items" :isRendered="isRendered(key)" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
    prop: ['items'],
    methods: {
        isRendered(key) {
            let total_items = this.items.length - 1;
            if (key === total_items) {
                this.$emit('onRendered');
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Instead of that , you should do with `mounted()`

Comment: You can check that vue [life cycle](https://vuejs.org/images/lifecycle.png) . Mounted is trigger after compile template or render ....

Comment: I've tried it putting in mounted but it doesn't work. I even tried to put it inside nexttick bust still no. That's why i directly call it in props

Comment: Is the loader component even necessary here? I see no asynchronous list loading happening; Vue will render the entire list all at once within the same update so the loader won't ever show.

Comment: Yes it is. I am trying to display a grid with 60 items. So while the loop is still on process, it only shows empty. That's when a need a loader so to inform the user that the item is being loaded. 60 items isn't really a problem in chrome as it loads it so fast, but the performance is different in IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is a misunderstanding in how exactly Vue updates its reactive properties.

I made a little demo for you hoping it clears it up.

https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-star-pzjhc

I would also recommend some reading from the Vue docs [computed properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html)

Comment: Thanks for the effort. Your sample code is kind of vue 3's suspense