# Refreshing a div or page in VUE.JS 2.0 after a v-for loop

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I'm using VUE.JS 2.0 and I have a page that has a b-tabs component with 2 tabs.  When I click on an option on tab page 1 it pulls data from a web server using AXIOS

```
           axios.get('https://wwwwwwwww.azurewebsites.net/api/formattedpubs/' + 
           self.new_researchers[0].PMIDS)
          .then(res => { 
             self.publicationData= res.data.New_Publications; 
           }
```

and builds the data on tab page 2 using a v-for loop.

```
            <div class="person-info" v-for="obj in publicationData" :key="obj.pmid"  v-bind:data-pmid='obj.pmid'  >
```

My problem is I need to know when it is finished being rendered because I have a third party component that runs a javascript function over the data and pulls in metrics from another resource.

```
       <div><div class='altmetric-embed' data-badge-type='donut' v-bind:data-pmid='obj.pmid' data-link-target='_blank' data-badge-popover='bottom' ></div></div>
```

according the readme file from the third party

> If you're adding Altmetric badges to the DOM after the page has
> loaded (via AJAX, for example) then you can ask the Altmetric embed
> script to search the page again for new matches by calling
> _altmetric_embed_init in Javascript:

The problem is that the page needs to be completely rendered before the badges can be put on.  If I click on another tab and then click back the badges are there.  If I put a button with the JavaScript refresh from the third party company they are there.  If I try to time the page to display by timing a programmatic function I can't get it to refresh first then call the other function.

Bottom line is how can I know when the page is rendered?  I tried mounted but since I need to know when the second tab is loaded it seems to fire when the first tab page is loaded.

I tried  [VUE - Call a function after v-for has done looping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60425378/vue-call-a-function-after-v-for-has-done-looping)

but that does not seem to work for the second refresh.  If I put into the isRendered function

```
       this.$forceUpdate();
```

I get an error in the console of

```
      [Vue warn]: You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function.
```

My fall back is to put a button that says "Show Metrics" but that's a last resort.  Sorry for being wordy Thanks

Comment: Perhaps after you set `self.publicationData` you can [await nextTick()](https://vuejs.org/api/general.html#nexttick) or perform the action you need within the [updated](https://vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle.html#updated) lifecycle hook which occurs after a rerender.

Comment: yoduh-- post your comment as an answer and I will mark it as the accepted answer.  I didn't see your comment but that is what I did anyway.  The updated did the trick

Comment: Thank you! I've done so.  Glad you got your code working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps after you set `self.publicationData` you can [await nextTick()](https://vuejs.org/api/general.html#nexttick), or perform the action you need within the [updated](https://vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle.html#updated) lifecycle hook which occurs after a rerender.